# FireFox toolbar plugin for executing quick jquery/CSS jobs

Tags: jquery, css, firefox, toolbar

is there a plugin (of that you know that I haven't found in google) that let's you execute/set tiny CSS properties per button click in the toolbar?

For example I have a website where I need to set certain things visible, certain invisible for testing purposes. I do that ith firebug now but I need to navigate to the element(s) every time and then display:none-them.

A button that would e.g. execute:

```
$('#id1').show();
$('.test').hide();
```

I don't want to add this to the code because I'm scared of my human being's behaviour of forgetting. And because it is an element that might cause the look of the site to be different.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could probably do, is create what's called a bookmarklet.

A bookmarklet is something that can run some code on the current page, from a link or 'bookmark' in your bookmark toolbar.

One of the most popular and obvious bookmarklet examples would probably be for Pinterest. If you've ever used it, they use a bookmarklet to run JS code that scrapes all the images from the current page. Very clever stuff, but fairly simple once you get your head around it.

There is a jQuery bookmarklet generator...try this link to see an example with your code in place:

http://benalman.com/code/test/jquery-run-code-bookmarklet/?name=Run+jQuery+Code&ver=1.3.2&code=%24%28%27%23id1%27%29.show%28%29%3B%0D%0A%24%28%27.test%27%29.hide%28%29%3B%0D%0A

You should see a big green button on it. This button will run your code. But what use is this on its own? What you need to do now, is **click and drag this button to your bookmarks bar** in your browser.

Then, when you click this now, on any page, it should run / execute as desired.

Hope this helps?
Mikey

Comment: Oh my god! This is amazing !! Thanks a million buddy.

Comment: Glad to be of help! Happy coding... :)